# Help identifying this LCD

Tags: lcd

I disassembled a broken kitchen scale and I found this LCD module:

https://imgur.com/a/8Uc3AHR

The module has only 2 wires (A(node) and K(athode) printed on the board).
I was wondering what kind of module is, I would like to reuse it in another project.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: (You should use the "add image" button to add images. That will upload them to Stack Exchange's special part of imgur. I didn't do it for you as they are not my images to copy.)

Comment: A and K are the anode and cathode connections for the LED backlight.

Answer (score 4):

You see those rubbery strips? They are [elastomeric connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector) (a.k.a zebra strips). They are used as the connectors between those gold-plated pads on the circuit board and the LCD. The red and black leads are most likely for an LED which is used as a backlight.

To re-use it, you would have to find out what each pad is for and re-create it on your own PCB - you should be able to re-use the zebra strips.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bare LCD glass. To reuse it, reverse engineer the connections and connect it to a MCU with built-in LCD glass controller or external LCD glass controller.